# Sharepoint List View Settings

Tags: sharepoint, list, view

We have created a new List View Style that shows thumbnails from a picture library, we have added a HyperLink Column and made the View style map the HyperLink url to an anchor tag.

The intention is that when the Content Managers want to create a image based list of hyper links they just have to create a Picture Library, and then add a web part view, and set the style to our new definition.

Its working OK - we have turned off lots of the toolbars, titles, borders etc - BUT there still remains a "Sort Bar" at the bottom that allows the user to change the order of the list. 
We want the option to turn this off - but we can't find the setting that turns it off.

Does anybody know?

[alt text http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/3674/sortbarrb4.png](http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/3674/sortbarrb4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Looks like I am wrong and you will have to use the CSS to hide the style bar.
It does feel a lot like a hack, but it has proven to be one that we have used out of a desire for some practicality in the developement costs.

Bugger!

**ORIGINAL**

You can edit the vwstyles.xml file in the 12 hive (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML). This controls exactly how the views look.
Unfortunately it is very ugly xml to render html.

I recommend you create your own vwstyle in the xml and set the style of the view to use the newly created one.

Comment: That's what we did to create the view's style. The 'Sort Bar' remains though.
We have removed it by changing the CSS - though this doesent feel the right way to do it.....

Comment: Not every feature in SharePoint is modifiable, except by modifying the template itself. That would be overkill, so hiding via CSS is a perfectly good solution to this.